# Updating Parse array with local array data, Swift, UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

When the tableview loads I retrieve the Parse Object "User", and load it into a userArray.

```
 func loadUserData(){


    var query = PFUser.query()


    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            println(error)

        } else if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

            println(objects)


            // loop through results. print(results)
            for object in objects {
                self.userArray.addObject(object)


                // code to download an image
                let imageFile = object["image"] as! PFFile

                imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {

                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        println(error)
                    } else {

                        if let data = imageData {
                            self.images.append(UIImage(data: data)!)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()



                        }
                    }

                }

            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

}
```

When a user selects a tableView cell, that PFUser.objectId is sent into an array of [selectedFriends], which is created at the top of the class.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    let row = indexPath.row
    let cellDataParse : PFObject = self.userArray.objectAtIndex(row) as! PFObject
    var user = userArray[row] as! PFUser
    var iD = user.objectId

    var selectedFriend = iD
    if cell?.selected == true {
    cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        // change made here ----????
    selectedFriends.append(selectedFriend!)
    println(selectedFriends)

    }

    if cell?.selected == false && selectedFriends.count == 2 {
            selectedFriends.removeAtIndex(1)
        }


 if self.selectedFriends.count > 5 {

var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Team Maximum", message: "Max team size is 5 friends\n You can only choose maximum 4 friends for your team.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: { action in


    self.selectedFriends.removeLast()
    cell?.accessoryType = .None
    cell?.selected = false





    })

}

    }
```

At this point I can successfully select a indexPath.row, and add the objectId of the user into the array of selectedFriends (Which I declared at the top of my class).

My goal is to take all of the objectId's added into the array, and send them to a Parse array called "team".

Here is the code for this:

```
 func createNewTeam(){

    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    if selectedFriends.count > 0 {
    user!.addObjectsFromArray([selectedFriends], forKey: "team")
    user!.saveInBackground()
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
    selectedFriends.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    println("something should have happend")
}
```

I then added this function to an action Button. When I pressed the button I got this error:

2015-09-09 12:52:56.651 Storm[11039:1498653] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Operation is invalid after previous operation.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023b3c65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001040cabb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   Storm                               0x0000000100dc2ae3 -[PFAddOperation applyToValue:forKey:] + 0
    3   Storm                               0x0000000100dd73bd -[PFObject(Private) performOperation:forKey:] + 206
    4   Storm                               0x0000000100ddea53 -[PFObject addObjectsFromArray:forKey:] + 126
    5   Storm                               0x0000000100d64596 _TFC5Storm29SearchTeamTableViewController13createNewTeamfS0_FT_T_ + 486
    6   Storm                               0x0000000100d5ebe4 _TFC5Storm29SearchTeamTableViewController18nextButtonDidPressfS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 68
    7   Storm                               0x0000000100d5ecd6 _TToFC5Storm29SearchTeamTableViewController18nextButtonDidPressfS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 54
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000102dffd62 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000102dffd62 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000102f1150a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000102f108d9 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000102e4c958 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000102e4d282 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000102e13541 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000102e20cdc _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000102dfb59c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001022e7431 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001022dd2fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001022dc934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001022dc366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010647ea3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000102dfe8c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  Storm                               0x0000000100d4c117 main + 135
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000104800145 start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I apologize. This is a lot to read. This is also my first post on stack overflow. Could someone help???

Comment: Also, nothing get's updated into parse.

Comment: do you want to save to parse or query

Answer (score 0):

Your query method is not efficient because you only downloaded images but again into the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method you tried to get the user objectID from it.
However you should have create a struct **outside of the Controller View class** that will contain the userid and the user's image.

your query function will now look like :

```
struct ModelStructure
{
var id:String!
var images:UIImage!
}
```

**Inside of the Controller class**

```
var arrayofData = [ModelStructure]()  // create an array of that structure 

  func loadUserData()
  {
      var query = PFQuery(className: "")
 query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error != nil
    {
        println(error)
    }
    else
    {
       if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]
       {
           for object in objects
           {
               var imageFile = object["image"] as! PFFile
               imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {(imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) ->Void in
                if error != nil
                {
                    println(error)
                }
                else
                {
                        if let data = imageData
                         {
                           var imagesToget = UIImage(data: data)
                            var oneModel = ModelStructure()
                            oneModel.id = object.objectId
                            oneModel.images = imagesToget
                            self.arrayofData.append(oneModel)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                }

               }
            }
        }

    }

    }

 }
```

**In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath you have this + what you wanted to do**

```
  var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    var data = self.arrayofData[indexPath.row]
    if cell?.selected == true {
        // add accessory
        cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        print("row that are being selected \(indexPath.row) \n")
        var selectUser = data.id
        self.selectedArray.append(selectUser)

    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out

Comment: did you fix the problem?